# Drupal hook_search_execute() is not function is not able to get customised result created from 3rd party API

Tags: drupal, search, hook

I have the search result coming from a thrid party website and storing the results in array.
I am trying to supply this search result to hook_search_execute() where it is not executing and giving me the results back. The hook_search_execute is to be used at a tab created with hook_search_info(). I need to have the new results shown when a user clicks on the tab created with hook_search_info().

Can anybody guide me what is wrong here, or has anybody landed in similar situation ans how they have dealt with this problem.

Env: Drupal 7

Comment: This is Fixed to me now. hook_search_execute picks the results array which throw form my search party search.

Comment: This is Fixed now. hook_search_execute picks the results array which throw form my search party search.